# How do I get the date a text message was sent to my Twilio number?

Tags: twilio

I try to get and analyse data from text with the Twilio API. With their example, I can get the phone number from the text is sent, but I would like to get the datetime and the body of the message.

For the phone nmber you just have to use that:

```
$phone = $_REQUEST['From'];
```

It works also for `To` and `Body` but I tried with DateSent and it's not working.

```
$date = $_REQUEST['DateSent'];
```

Do you have an idea about what could be the word to get it?

Comment: One thing I like to do before diving into the use of any input/response is dump all the data that's received in a typical interaction (be it the _REQUEST data, like you're working with here, or JSON/XML responses in other situations), and save that off to my project notes (usually an Evernote notebook) in a prettified format for reference throughout the project. This way I know exactly what's available/expected in a proper scenario & how I can access it. I also avoid poor/outdated documentation this way (speaking generally here, not specific to Twilio's docs).

Comment: @webcalif Accept some answers

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) the date is not sent as a parameter. However, you can use the Rest API to [retrieve the SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms) using the `$_REQUEST['SmsSid']`, and the returned data will contain a `DateCreated`.

**Note**: As John commented, unless you really need the 'official' timestamp, it's essentially  the current time. Also note that if you try to query the API for a message that just came in, it may not have propagated, so you may not not get the data you're requesting.

If there's some use case where you can't just use the current timestamp, that would be interesting.

Comment: There's no DateSent because it's `now()` for when your URL is requested. We request the URL as soon as the message comes in.

Comment: @JohnSheehan And I guess I should note that if you try to request via the REST API right when it comes it, it may not actually be there yet. At least I know that's happened on incoming phone calls.

Comment: Thanks, I use the current datatime.